# Devise sign_in_params method missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm attempting to use Devise (2.2.4), which I'm new to, with the Rails 3.2.13/Ruby 2.0.0p195 app I'm building. I turned scoped_views on because I want to have my own separate users and admins views. And I created my own Users::RegistrationsController which seems to be doing what I want it to. I've just added my own Users::SessionsController, which is where I've hit problems.

I straight copied over a couple of action methods from the Devise::SessionsController source as a first step, planning to modify them once they were working (my controller code is at the bottom of this post). But my 'new' method is failing, when called, with a NameError because `sign_in_params' is apparently undefined.

Well, that seems pretty strange because I'm inheriting from Devise::SessionsController, and when I look at the [**source for that**](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/270e2ece19f20fdbb349b8130c31acc5b222fabb/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb) on GitHub, there's the sign_in_params defined in the protected section at the bottom. So I decided to investigate whether my controller is inheriting correctly from Devise::SessionsController - and it certainly seem to be. I can list out all the inherited methods, just not that one missing one. So I ended up running the following piece of code in the Rails Console:

```
    (Devise::SessionsController.new.methods - DeviseController.new.methods).each {|m| puts m}
```

And it produces the following output:

```
    _one_time_conditions_valid_68?
    _one_time_conditions_valid_72?
    _callback_before_75
    _one_time_conditions_valid_76?
    new
    create
    destroy
    serialize_options
    auth_options
```

If I ignore the underscored methods, the remainder are all those methods defined in the Devise::SessionsController source **except** sign_in_params. I can't see how anything I've written can be deleting that method, and I can't think what else to try. Google is silent on this problem, so I assume I'm doing something uniquely foolish, but I can't work out what. Any suggestions please? And might someone else try running that bit of Rails Console code to see what they get?

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController 
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
  prepend_before_filter :allow_params_authentication!, :only => :create
  prepend_before_filter { request.env["devise.skip_timeout"] = true }

  # GET /resource/sign_in
  def new
    self.resource = resource_class.new(sign_in_params)
    clean_up_passwords(resource)
    respond_with(resource, serialize_options(resource))
  end

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using code from a devise version compatible with Rails 4 on a rails 3 application.

`sign_in_params` is a method to be used with [strong parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters). A gem used in rails 4.

If you check the controller on devise version 2.2. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/v2.2/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb

You will see that there is no `sign_in_params` method.

Check which version of devise you are using and copy the code based on that devise version in your controller, rather than the latest code from github.

Comment: Thanks, Arjan. You're quite right. The 'master' branch on GitHub that the Devise Wiki links to seems to be a newer version than the current gem. I even checked the README for the master branch, which has a badge right at the top saying 'gem version 2.2.4', but now that you have pointed out that I can explicitly select the source for version 2.2 I can see that you're correct. I assume the 'gem version 2.2.4' badge I checked isn't referring to the branch it appears in, but just tells you what the current release version is. I'll have to get better at working out what GitHub is telling me.